# Elasticsearch-Hadoop formatting multi resource writes issue

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-hadoop

I am interfacing Elasticsearch with Spark, using the Elasticsearch-Hadoop plugin and I am having difficulty writing a dataframe with a `timestamp` type column to Elasticsearch.

The problem is when I try to write using dynamic/multi resource formatting to create a daily index.

From the [relevant documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-multi-writes-format) I get the impression that this is possible, however, the python example below fails to run unless I change my dataframe type to `date`.

```
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars', 'elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.1.2.jar')
conf.set('es.nodes', '127.0.0.1:9200')
conf.set('es.read.metadata', 'true')
conf.set('es.nodes.wan.only', 'true')
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
before = now - timedelta(days=1)
after = now + timedelta(days=1)
cols = ['idz', 'name', 'time']
vals = [(0,'maria', before), (1, 'lolis', after)]  
time_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
```

When I try to write, I use the following:

```
time_df.write.mode('append').format(
    'org.elasticsearch.spark.sql'
).options(
    **{'es.write.operation': 'index' }
).save('xxx-{time|yyyy.MM.dd}/1')
```

Unfortunatelly this renders an error:

> .... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2018-03-04 12:36:12.949897" is malformed at " 12:36:12.949897"   at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)

On the other hand this works perfectly fine if I use dates when I create my dataframe:

```
cols = ['idz', 'name', 'time']
vals = [(0,'maria', before.date()), (1, 'lolis', after.date())]  
time_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
```

Is it possible to format a dataframe `timestamp` to be written to daily indexes with this method, without also keeping a `date` column around? How about monthly indexes?

> Pyspark version:
>   spark version 2.2.1
>   Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_151
>
> ElasticSearch version 
>   number    "6.2.2" build_hash  "10b1edd"
>   build_date    "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z" build_snapshot    false
>   lucene_version    "7.2.1" minimum_wire_compatibility_version  "5.6.0"
>   minimum_index_compatibility_version   "5.0.0"